# difference between <'T> and <T>?

Tags: f#

I tried googling but I cannot find the difference between < 'T > and < T >?

Comment: Also read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233183.aspx.

Comment: In short, 'T is a generic type and T is a concrete type (e.g. List or Object).